# Указатели и ссылки (Прошу помочь разобраться в "чтении" этого добра) [C++]

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки

Помогите новичку разобраться) 
Для начала распишу как я "читаю" код в компиляторе.
Допустим у меня есть:

```
int a=0;
int b=10;
a=b;
```

Заострю внимание на: "a=b" и прочитаю я это как: значению переменной "а" присвоить значение переменной "b". После чего значение "a" станет равно 10.

Вообщем. Возьмем к примеру ссылку.

```
int a = 5; 
int &b = a; //b - ссылка на а 
b = 10; //в а тоже стало 10
```

Как я понял с помощью амперсанда мы получаем настоящий адрес переменной, а не её буквенный синоним. `int &b=a;` Я прочитал бы как: адресу переменной `b` присвоить ЗНАЧЕНИЕ переменной `a`. То бишь вместо адреса к примеру `0x22ff08` у меня будет просто 5 (И по адресу 5 естественно никакого числа бы уже не было). Но это как я понимаю) А на деле то оказывается, что читать нужно как: адресу переменной `b` присвоить `a` , а именно саму БУКВУ "a", но не в коем случае не её содержание. Я правильно это понял? И никак не могу понять почему везде мы пишем одинаково, но к примеру когда я пишу `b=a` это значит что я приравниваю значение этих переменных, а когда `int &b=a;`, то тут уже адресу присваиваю именно букву. У меня просто начинает припекать уже почему все понимают, а я не понимаю. Пожалуйста помогите разобраться.

Comment: И ещё забыл кое что спросить. 
Допустим:
int var = 123; 
int *ptrvar = &var;

Почему если я уберу *, то будет ошибка. Разве я не могу просто в обычную переменную сохранить адрес var? Или я обязательно должен это делать в разыименованную переменную?

Comment: Воспринимайте ссылку как синоним переменной. Тогда Вам полегчает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

> int a=0; int b=10; b=a;

переменной Б присваивается значение переменной А

2)

> int a = 5;  int &b = a; //b - ссылка на а  b = 10; //в а тоже стало 10

Переменная Б является ссылкой на адрес памяти переменной А.

Т.е. в 1 случае: А - получает выделенный адрес памяти, где хранит свое значение. и Б получает адрес памяти где хранит свое значение. И дальше мы говорит b=a, т.е. в адрес значения b записать значение из адреса памяти a.

Во 2 случае А - получает выделенный адрес памяти, где хранит свое значение.
А вот переменная Б не имеет своего выделенного адреса, она является ссылкой на тот же адрес в памяти что и А. И все действия с Б, будут отражаться на адресе памяти где хранится значение А, т.е. они будут всегда иметь одно и то же значение, т.к. ссылаются на один и тот же адресс памяти.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Вроде бы понял. Просто ни как не могу принять это как факт, что нужно читать именно так) Мозг всё равно при виде такой строчки int &b = a;  продолжает читать как я писал выше.

Comment: По указателям: http://ci-plus-plus-snachala.ru/?p=34

Comment: Дело привычки и времени на осознание разных синтаксисов в разных языках. Я сума сошел после того как стал программировать на Oracle имея до этого дело только с MySQL, так же как и программировать на VB.NET имея до этого дело только с Delphi ))) Со временем все осваивается, воображение, осознание развивается и ваш мозг начнет улавливать суть. Главное понимать как хранится информация, к которой вы обращаетесь через переменные и как вы к ней обращаетесь.

Answer (score 2):

Неразбериха возникла из-за того, что на знак амперсанда возложено несколько задач. Для того, чтобы понять разницу, рассмотрим, как подобный функционал может быть реализован с помощью языка Си:

```
int a = 10;
int* b = &a;
*b = 5;
```

Первая строка не претерпела изменений, поэтому, оставим ее без внимания.
Вторая строка изменилась следующим образом:

1. Переменная `b` теперь имеет тип *указатель на `int`*. Обратите внимание на звездочку после названия типа. Стоит отметить, что в языке Си нет ссылок, есть только указатели. Фактически, в переменной `b` хранится адрес переменной типа `int`.
2. Переменной `b` присваивается адрес переменной `a`. Обратите внимание, когда амперсанд стоит перед именем переменной, это означает, что мы берем ее адрес.

Третья строка также несколько преобразилась:

1. Перед `b` появилась звездочка - это означает, что мы обращаемся к *области памяти*, по адресу, записанному в переменной `b` (разыменовываем указатель). Поскольку в переменной `b` хранится адрес переменной `a`, мы запишем в переменную `a` константу `5`.

Теперь плавно перейдем на С++. Приведенный код будет справедлив для С++, но теперь в нашем распоряжении есть ссылки. Рассмотрим аналогичный код, но с использованием ссылок:

```
int a = 10;
int& b = a;
b = 5;
```

Первая строка не интересна.
Вторая строка изменилась следующим образом:

1. Теперь тип переменной `b` - *ссылка на `int`*. Отличия между ссылкой и указателем следующие:

   1. Ссылка должна быть инициализирована при создании, после чего нельзя изменить адрес, на который она ссылается.
   2. При обращении к области памяти, на который указывает ссылка нет необходимости ее разыменовывать.
2. При инициализации мы указываем, что ссылка `b` указывает на переменную `a`.

В третьей строке мы записываем по ссылке значение `5`. Нам нет необходимости ее разыменовывать, это произойдет автоматически.

Comment: Спасибо) Вроде уже понял суть. Часто ли вообще придётся работать с ссылками и указателями в каких-то крупных программах или это узконаправленно всё?

Comment: В C++ постоянно идет работа с константными ссылками, чтобы избежать ненужного копирования при передаче переменной в функцию. Полиморфизм в ООП, работа с массивами, и т.д. Они повсюду. Другой вопрос в том, что все это дело может стать причиной неочевидных и трудноуловимых ошибок. Поэтому используются различные обертки:`std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr` и иже с ними.